# Left Join on subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, subquery

Can someone help me with this query? In the subquery P, a fiscal year exists where the same year does not exist in BudgetActivityDetailCurrentBiennium. I need this query to show a null value for Amount in that year. Currently that year does not show up at all.

```
SELECT
    P.FiscalYear
   ,P.BudgetNbr
   ,SUM(sec.BudgetActivityDetailCurrentBiennium.TranAmount) AS Amount
FROM 

(SELECT
  sec.BudgetIndexCurrentBiennium.BudgetNbr
  ,AVG(CAST(sec.BudgetIndexCurrentBiennium.BienniumYear AS INT)+1) AS FiscalYear
FROM
  sec.BudgetIndexCurrentBiennium
GROUP BY
  sec.BudgetIndexCurrentBiennium.BudgetNbr

UNION ALL

SELECT
  sec.BudgetIndexCurrentBiennium.BudgetNbr
  ,AVG(CAST(sec.BudgetIndexCurrentBiennium.BienniumYear AS INT)+2) AS FiscalYear
FROM
  sec.BudgetIndexCurrentBiennium 
GROUP BY
 sec.BudgetIndexCurrentBiennium.BudgetNbr) AS P

LEFT JOIN sec.BudgetActivityDetailCurrentBiennium
   ON
    P.BudgetNbr = sec.BudgetActivityDetailCurrentBiennium.BudgetNbr
AND P.FiscalYear = sec.BudgetActivityDetailCurrentBiennium.FiscalYear
WHERE sec.BudgetActivityDetailCurrentBiennium.BudgetNbr = '076036'
GROUP BY 
P.FiscalYear
,P.BudgetNbr
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is your `WHERE` clause,

```
WHERE sec.BudgetActivityDetailCurrentBiennium.BudgetNbr = '076036'
```

which applies to the `SELECT` as a whole, not just (as I guess you intend) to the left join.

Change the `WHERE` to an `AND`. That should do the trick.

Comment: An alternative is: `WHERE sec.BudgetActivityDetailCurrentBiennium.BudgetNbr = '076036' or sec.BudgetActivityDetailCurrentBiennium.BudgetNbr is NULL`. The point is to allow an `OUTER JOIN` to produce NULL values without disposing of them in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Or you could use `WHERE COALESECE(sec.BudgetActivityDetailCurrentBiennium.BudgetNbr, '076036') = '076036'`. That'd also work.